# Kirby-selector not working

Tags: php, kirby

Hi I am trying use this https://github.com/storypioneers/kirby-selector in my project in Kirby 2.2.3. I was downloaded zip form this link, unpack and copied to `site/plugins/`. So zip content is in `site/plugins/kirby-selector-master`.

In blueprint i have:

```
fields:
  postimage:
    label: Main Post Image
    type: selector
    mode: single
  types:
    - image
```

But if i want edit image in panel i have got a message: `The selector field is missing. Please add it to your installed fields or remove it from your blueprint`

I am trying a lot of combinations - remove `kirby-selector-master` to `selector` or file `field-selector.php` remove to `selector.php` but after that i have php errors....

Answer (score 1):

- You need to create a folder called 'fields' under /sites (i.e.
  `sites/fields`).
- Place the entire 'field' folder from the zip    package into
  `sites/fields` (i.e. `sites/fields/field`).
- Rename 'field' folder to 'selector' (i.e. `sites/fields/selector`)
  and it should work.